# Cleveref to Nomenclature?

Tags: cleveref, nomenclature

I am writing a `book` and use `nomencl` to print a list of symbols at the end. How do I cleveref to this list? In the introduction of the book, I would like to write something like "All the notation we use can be found in `\cref{...}`", where LaTeX should replace `\cref{...}` by the name of the nomenclature list, i.e. by `\nomrefname`.

Using the `intoc` option or the `\addcontentsline` command, I managed to get an entry for the list of symbols in the table of contents, but when I put something like `\label{SectionNomenclature}` before or after my `\printnomenclature` and try `\cref{SectionNomenclature}` I am referenced to the last chapter before the list of symbols. :(

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}     %nomenclature
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}       %hyperlink references
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}   %automatic clever references


\makenomenclature

\nomenclature[N]{$\mathbb{N}$}{the natural numbers $\N=\{0,1,2, \ldots \}$}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction}

\chapter{Overview}

\section{Blabla}

All the symbols used can be found in \cref{SectNomenclature}.

\printnomenclature

\label{SectNomenclature}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already loading `hyperref`, you can patch `\thenomenclature` to use `\phantomsection` (to generate an anchor) and to add the `\label`; since you are interested in getting the title of the sectional unit, use `\nameref`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\chapter*{\nomname}}
  {\phantomsection\chapter*{\nomname}\label{SectNomenclature}}
  {}
  {}

\makenomenclature

\nomenclature[N]{$\mathbb{N}$}{the natural numbers $\N=\{0,1,2, \ldots \}$}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction}
\chapter{Overview}
\section{Test section}

All the symbols used can be found in~\nameref{SectNomenclature}.

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's no need to pass the `pdftex` option to `hyperref`; the right driver will be automatically detected.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Gonzalo Medina's answer, you make the `\cref` command work by introducing a new counter and refstepping it at the start of the Nomenclature section.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[refpage,intoc,notocbasic]{nomencl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\newcounter{nomencl}
\crefformat{nomencl}{#2Nomenclature#3}

\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\chapter*{\nomname}}
  {\clearpage\refstepcounter{nomencl}\chapter*{\nomname}\label{SectNomenclature}}
  {}
  {}

\makenomenclature

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}

\nomenclature[N]{$\mathbb{N}$}{the natural numbers $\N=\{0,1,2, \ldots \}$}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction}
\chapter{Overview}
\section{Test section}

All the symbols used can be found in~\cref{SectNomenclature}.

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

The `notocbasic` option is need in recent versions to make this work.

Comment: Great answer! It works well with the `titlesec` package and with the table of contents (as opposed to the other answer). So thank you!

Comment: Dear Andrew, your code does not work anymore with TeXLive 2022, do you know why and how to patch it?

Comment: I asked a follow-up question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659678/cleveref-to-nomenclature-version-2022

Comment: @Watson Thank you for pointing this out.  The definition of `thenomenclature` has changed, so the simplest solution is to pass the option `notocbasic` to the package `nomenclature`.  If that is not acceptable to you I can look further into this.

Comment: @AndrewSwann : thanks, it worked!

Comment: @daleif When `tocbasic` is in effect the patch section of code is circumvented, and handling of the heading is dealt with by the `tocbasic` functionality instead.  As yet I don't know how to patch into the `tocbasic` handling.  Previously `nomencl` didn't use `tocbasic`, now it is set as the default handling method.